# Run multiple Robot test cases in a sequence using PyCharm?

Tags: python-2.7, testing, plugins, pycharm, robotframework

After installing **Intelibot** and **Robot FW** *plugins* in PyCharm, now I can successfully run Robot FW test cases from PyCharm.

But is there a way to automatically execute multiple test suites from PyCharm, one after the other?

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Normally when you run a suite of tests, all of the tests by default execute one after the other. Are you saying that when you have a file with more than one test, only one test is running? Or, when you say "test" do you actually mean a "file" with more than one test?

Comment: @BryanOakley, yeah I mean test suites one after the other. I'll edit in the post

Comment: [Setup the run configuration in PyCharm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256070/running-tests-on-pycharm-using-robot-framework/42463140#42463140) and then just pass the suites you want to be ran as a parameter.