# How to add parameter of ride into pycharm

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I have worked in ride for my test robotframework
And now I want to work with Pycharm
I have a problem because I haven't found the solution to integrated my paremeter in ride to pycharm
here is parameter to run test in ride:

--variable individual:yes --variable Environment:M4C --variable Lang:fr -d C:\TestAuto\log\20170221M4C01user_managemements

When I try to add this in pycharm in File > Settings > tools>External Tools> parameter i have this

C:\Python27\Scripts\pybot.bat --variable individual:yes --variable Environment:M4C --variable Lang:fr -d C:\TestAuto\log\20170221M4C01user_managemements
[ ERROR ] Expected at least 1 argument, got 0

thank's for your helps

Comment: What's missing is what actually should be executed  - the test suite(s), and optionally a section of them. Look at this q/a - it's how to create a run configuration in PyCharm, a more powerful solution than external tool - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42463140/3446126

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running tests on PyCharm using Robot Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256070/running-tests-on-pycharm-using-robot-framework)