# How to run test cases based on tags in pycharm robot framework

Tags: tags, pycharm, robotframework

How to run test cases based on tags in pycharm robot framework

For example- i have one test case (robot file) with tag -  Testing. Similarly i have another two robot file with Tag  - Sanity. Suppose if i want to run only the sanity tag test cases , how can i .

Comment: Look at this answer [how to set up cases execution in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256070/running-tests-on-pycharm-using-robot-framework/42463140#42463140), and to run specific tag, add the parameter `--include your_tag_name`.

Comment: just an advice, if you are using robot framework why don't you use another IDE like RIDE? where you can easily write code and run a singol test case, test suit or the entire project

Answer (score 7):

To run specific testcases in a file or a directory use :

```
--include tagName #you can use it multiple times
```

Similarly if you want to exclude some testcases, use :

```
--exclude tagName
```

You can also use patterns, See examples here : http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tag-patterns

Answer (score 1):

To run tests with specific tag from a directory execute as the following:

robot -i  path/to/the/test/suite/file.robot

Answer (score 1):

Use the following arguments to start your test

--include  to include a tag you wanna run
--exclude  to exclude a tag you wanna exclude

you can also use AND, OR and NOT like this --include loginANDlogoutNOTreset

Yes, you use like that, without spaces

Answer (score 0):

To run tags in robot framework in the terminal you need to include `-i` and the Tag name.

so for example

```
    ***Test Case***
Example test
    [Documentation] About the example test
    [Tags]  Sanity  Testing
```

In your Pycharm terminal run

```
robot -d results -i Sanity Tests/pathName
```

You can include the path name if your want to only check for tags in that path.
If you include the folder name rather than the path it run all tests with that Tag name.

Answer (score 0):

you can type in console for include tags(xyz= your robot class name):

```
robot -i tagname xyz.robot
```

and for exclude:

```
robot -e tagname xyz.robot
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to setup your Robot test run using Pycharm:

1. Go to Run >> Edit Configuration
2. - Add New Configuration
3. Give it whatever name (Sanity Run)
4. In your Script path, add your runner (Python\Scripts\pabot or run.py)
5. Add your parameters (--include  yourtag  -v  variable:value  --variablefile  path-to-your-variablefile
6. Set your Python interpreter and your working dir

Save your configuration and execute your tagged tests easily by pressing the green play button. This might be too much info for what you just asked but it can help someone else.