# Unable to Run .Robot file in Pycharm windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

Iam new to Robot framework . 
I have installed below.

```
Python 3.7.0
Pycharm 2018.1.4 community edition
Robot framework 3.0.4 
robotframework==3.0.4
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.1.1
```

I also set the environment variable --> path  as "C:\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Python37-32 "

In pycharm Created a new Demo.robot file .
In Pycharm --> tools-->External tools--> set the 'program' as 'C:\Python37-32\Scripts\robot.bat' and 'working directory' as 'C:\Python37-32\Scripts' .

In Pycharm 'Run/debug configuration'-->'Script path' set as 'C:\Users\inmj\PycharmProjects\PycharmProject1\Demo.robot'
'Python Interpreter' as 'Python 3.7 (PycharmProject1)'

Tried running below script in Pycharm

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  sample
Library  SeleniumLibrary
```

It gives me error as below

C:\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/inmj/PycharmProjects/PycharmProject1/Demo.robot
  File "C:/Users/inmj/PycharmProjects/PycharmProject1/Demo.robot", line 1

```
*** Settings ***
 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Could anyone please help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running tests on PyCharm using Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256070/running-tests-on-pycharm-using-robot-framework)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute a Robot script directly with a Python interpreter.  Python interpreters only understand Python code, not Robot syntax.

you need to execute your Robot scripts through the robot runner.
see: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-robot-framework

Comment: Thanks @Corey . the attached document says to run on command line and i need to know the settings in Pycharm .I created the .Robot file in pycharm and Now i tried In Pycharm --> tools-->External tools--> set the 'program' as 'C:\Python37-32\Scripts\pybot.bat'  and still the same issue .

Comment: you need to pass your .robot script as an argument to pybot.

Comment: Hi @Corey , Thanks much . I passed the script as an argument in External tools ,  and in Run/Debug configuration selected Script path as 'C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\robot\run.py ' . It works fine now .