# Importing Selenium Library for Robot Framework on Mac

Tags: robotframework

I am having issues importing Selenium Library (latest version) for Robot Framework on PyCharm on Mac OS (Mojave). PyCharm is showing Python version of 3.7, python -V command in the terminal returns 2.7 though.

Chromedriver is in usr/local/bin, in this directory there are gecodriver, python 3.7.1.pkg, Selenium Library - master folder.

Yep, I am new to it.
Is it a compatibility thing, the path?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what are the actual issues importing the library? You did not tell that part. Obviously the pycharm uses different python than the default in the shell; in which one did you install the SeleniumLibrary, and where do you see the issues.

Comment: The issue is when start typing the keyword in my project, it gets highlighted, i.e.


*** Test Cases ***
User must sign in to check out
    [Documentation]  Basic info
    [Tags]  Smoke
    Open Browser      - here (It says, keyword definition is not found)

In the Setting section above it, it says 'import file' not  found here, when I hover over 'Selenium':

*** Settings ***
Documentation  Basic info
Library  Selenium . - here

PS Changed python version to 2.7 - didn't help.

Comment: Was playing back and forth with the versions. Now everything is working. 
Closing the question.

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256070/running-tests-on-pycharm-using-robot-framework/42463140#42463140. It is how to setup pycharm for execution, yet: in the first step of it, be sure you have configured the default project's interpreter to be the same one, as the one where the SeleniumLibrary is installed through `pip`.