# 'robot is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, automated-tests, robotframework

**Problem:** I am trying to running my Dummy.robot test script in the terminal via cmd line: `robot -d results tests/dummy.robot`. However, it is returning the error 'robot' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I sensed that perhaps the robotframework was not properly installed or in the correct directory because the keywords "Open Browser" (see below) was already detected as invalid syntax prior to running.

**Troubleshooting Methods:**

1. Checked that both robotframework and robotframework-seleniumlibarary were installed
2. Installed intellibot on PyCharm and restarted IDE
3. Made sure I provided the correct path to the script within my project directory as shown below.
4. Checked that Python 39 and Python39/Scripts was added to my PATH although I am not sure if this is relevant because it just allows me to use pip for installing robotframework later.
5. Selected the interpreter for this "dummy" project from where that python.exe is located.

**Source Screenshots:**

File Structure

[image]

Run Config & Updated File Structure (3/8/21)

[image]

Source Code

[image]

Terminal

[image]

RF Library Location
[image]

Comment: Is your virtualenvironment called "base"? What is the output if you run `pip list` in the same command prompt session?

Comment: And in general it is much more preferable if instead of running it in command line, you set up a run configuration for Robot Framework - thus you will use the full capabilities of the IDE, like go to source, debugging etc. Here's how to do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463140/3446126

Comment: @TodorMinakov, I was actually trying to set up a run configuration through that post you linked. Sorry for the stupid question, but is the working directory the full path to my current project folder, "dummy" in this case. I attached my run config as well as the latest file structure. I am still unable to run that command stated above. Thanks!

Comment: "... is the working directory the full path to my current project folder ..." - yes, it is the full one, "C:\Users\.....\robot-scripts\dummy" in your case. What is the error you are getting when you use the run config, now? Are RF and SeleniumLIbrary installed in your system python installation - vs a virtual environment? And, what's the output of `pip list` -when ran in command line, and with the correct python environment ?

Comment: I have RF and SeleniumLibrary installed, but how can I verify where it's in the system python? I checked within the site pkgs of my Python39 directory (see above), and I thiiink those are the correct libraries. Unfortunately, the error remains the exact same as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I think, going by your terminal pic, it looks like you have a virtual environment: (base). As @TodorMinakov suggested, fire the command `pip list` in your terminal path (same path as shown in the pic). If Robot Framework libs exist there, then it should be fine. Then try the command `python -m robot -d results tests/dummy.robot` But if libs are not in the folder, then you have to do pip install for them from Terminal for right installation (which means, your installed libs are in your native directory while you are working in virtual env).

Since you are working with Pycharm IDE, it is better if you could use its terminal instead of using a command line tool such as bash or command prompt. Try this too.

To check if the libs installed are in System Python, you have to go to your folder site packages (eg: C://Python39/Lib/site-packages), you would find all the natively installed libraries here. In case of virtual environment, you have to check in your present directory (where the code exists). There should be a folder by the name venv (or 'base'), which will comprise of the python paths eg: (venv/Lib/site-packages)

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue and it was a pip versioning issue. It got resolved after installing the upgraded pip version and then reinstalling the robot framework and Appium library. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the terminal in Admin mode.
2. pip uninstall robotframework
3. upgrade pip
4. again pip install robotframework